# css horizontal menu is outside of round div layer

Tags: html-lists, overlap, css

I am trying to make my horizontal menu have round edges, however the inner "li" elements seem to overlap the div layer.

Here is an example for what I mean:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
</ul>
```

```
.menu {
     background-color:#CCC;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    z-index:9999999;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:-9999;
}

li {
    display:inline;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:-9999;
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3zeUg/
Have a look at the very left li element, it overlaps with it's square border into the round border.

I tried setting z-indexes without any success. I also tried giving the li elements a round border, but then each of the elements has a round border, which I don't want and since I am working on a wordpress theme, I should stick to the standards that are given.

I came across this website here: http://mypeoplesrock.com/ and in the menu you can see he has round borders but the inside element doesn't overlap. Looking at his css file, I can't seem to find what he did differently.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to `.menu` to prevent inner elements to bleed through the border.

Use the positioning method of your choice to refine the layout inside of the menu afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **text-indent**;

```
ul {
...
text-indent: 15px;
...
}
```

or **margin-left**;

```
ul {
...
margin: 0 0 0 15px;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `padding-left: 5px;` to your `.menu` CSS

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/MUrb7/)

```
li:first-child{
   border-top-left-radius:10px; 
   border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just play around with the padding inside of `.menu`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
 background-color:#CCC;
border-radius:10px;
border:1px solid black;
z-index:9999999;
padding: 10px;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index:-9999;
}

li {
display:inline;
background-color:red;
z-index:-9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding "overflow: hidden" to the "menu" class. This will hide the parts of the list going outside of the div.

```
.menu {
     background-color:#CCC;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    z-index:9999999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You could also try adding rounded corners to the first list element in the list.

```
li:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
li:first-child {
   -moz-border-top-left-radius:10px;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
   border-top-left-radius:10px;
   -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}
```